# Spark configurations for Out of memory error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Cluster setup -

```
Driver has 28gb
Workers have 56gb each (8 workers)
```

Configuration -

```
spark.memory.offHeap.enabled true
spark.driver.memory 20g
spark.memory.offHeap.size 16gb
spark.executor.memory 40g
```

My job -

```
//myFunc just takes a string s and does some transformations on it, they are very small strings, but there's about 10million to process.


//Out of memory failure
data.map(s => myFunc(s)).saveAsTextFile(outFile)

//works fine
data.map(s => myFunc(s))
```

Also, I de-clustered / removed spark from my program and it completed just fine(successfully saved to a file) on a single server with 56gb of ram.  This shows that it just a spark configuration issue.  I reviewed https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#memory-management and the configurations I currently have seem to be all that should be needed to be changed for my job to work.  What else should I be changing?

Update -

Data -

```
val fis: FileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(inputFile))
val bis: BufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
val input: CompressorInputStream = new CompressorStreamFactory().createCompressorInputStream(bis);
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input))
val stringArray = br.lines().toArray()
val data = sc.parallelize(stringArray)
```

Note - this does not cause any memory issues, even though it is incredibly inefficient.  I can't read from it using spark because it throws some EOF errors. (So please do not recommend to use spark builtin file reading)

myFunc, I can't really post the code for it because it's complex.  But basically, the input string is a deliminated string, it does some deliminator replacement, date/time normalizing and things like that.  The output string will be roughly the same size as an input string.

Also, it works fine for smaller data sizes, and the output is correct and roughly the same size as input data file, as it should be.

Comment: This is the same question with the same answer as yesterday, your solution or paralleling a large array won't work because it blows up memory,  you might be able to get this to work if you can give the driver more memory.  Since you can run this without spark, why not just do that?

Comment: @puhlen because it takes to long.  does is create a full copy of the array every time or what? I mean, I can run this on a 16gb server without spark, yet here I have almost 400gb of memory at my disposal with spark and it runs out.